# Is it good to take protein supplements?

Tags: cardio, bodybuilding, protein, supplements

I have just joined the gym and it has been a month since I have started the gym. I have done cardio for 3 weeks and 1 week body building
but the problem is that while doing cardio I used to get tired little early and wasn't able to do little hardcore cardio.

For example: I couldn't do plank continuously for 1 minute.

So my coach told me that I don't have stamina and I should start taking  protein or prework out which will help me in my workout.

Now I have started doing body building and my coach ask me to do 20 - 25 reps in each of my sets like biceps, shoulder, chest etc and so what happens is
while doing 3 sets, in 2nd or 3rd rep I do some 10 -15 repetitions so my coach is telling me to take protein powder but I have a concern that using protein
powder have some negative effects on body and when I will quit gym, I will lose all my pumping.

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your primary nutrition should be from food. Protein powder as the name suggest are supplements, if you are using them as food, it may come up with side-effects. Regarding your coach, it's time to get a new one. You are a beginner, and with proper diet, nutrition, rest  and workout, you can see benefits, not just by pumping yourself with protein powder. It's obvious that your coach is trying to sell you stuffs, or has something to do with the product supplier. I have known such people personally, who egg newbies to goon high dosage of protein.

Build your stamina slowly by doing cardio. Nothing comes overnight magically, and you shouldn't be expecting it. Remember,your journey towards good health is a marathon, not a short sprint.

Comment: Your last 2 sentence are really really motivating and it build some confidence in me.Thank you thank you so much sir.actually i was concerned and scared that i wont be able to do body building as the way i was told so

Comment: Always happy to help, and you're welcome. You can do it, it just needs time. Some people are hard-gainers, so just keep doing the good work. Your competition should be with you, you should aim to be better than what you were. Don't compete with others, you may never know what they are headed towards. Just relax and focus, you will do fine.

Answer (score 4):

Protein supplements such as whey protein powder can be very beneficial, especially to strength trainees and bodybuilders.  If your stamina is reduced due to under-nourishment (for example, a caloric deficit) then protein supplements may improve your stamina; but, if you are under-nourished, then you will have a very difficult time trying to build your muscles.

Multiple sets of 20-25 repetitions is are not ideal for increasing muscular strength or size; they are essentially a form of metabolic conditioning.  Instead, consider doing three sets of five repetitions of compound barbell movements such as the squat, deadlift, and overhead press.

Comment: Do you really think that more repetitons does not aid in growing muscles because more reps more exercise and more growth i guess.please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Learning Check out this question and the answers.
http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32423/defining-muscle-vs-building-muscle

Comment: @Learning, yes, low-repetition high-intensity exercise stimulates muscle growth better than high-repetition low-intensity exercise.  [General Adaptation Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28biology%29#General_adaptation_syndrome) is relevant here.  Strength is the ability to produce force against an external resistance, and muscular force-production ability is closely related to muscle size (cross-sectional area).  To achieve a strength _adaptation_ (and muscular growth), we need to apply an appropriate _stress_: in this case, demand that the body produce more force (lift heavy).